# Codeigniter 4 - how to get the first row and the last row of a result

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am trying to get the first row and the last row of a query result.  I see from Ci4's docs, there are two methods to help, namley, `getFirstRow([$type = 'object'])` and `getLastRow([$type = 'object'])` but I am having difficulty using them.  Here is my method so far:

```
function getLoginFailCount($login_fail_ip, $max_login_attempts = 3, $within_seconds = 320){
    $builder = $this->builder('login_fail');
    $builder->where('login_fail_ip', $login_fail_ip);
    $builder->orderBy('login_fail_created_at','DESC');
    $query = $builder->get(3);
    print_r($query->getFirstRow($query));
}
```

I get an error at getFirstRow as follows;

```
Argument 1 passed to CodeIgniter\Database\BaseResult::getFirstRow() must be 
of the type string, object given
```

How can I get `getFirstRow()` to work?  Doesn't this doc definition say I need to pass it an `object`?  Why does the error say it my be of type `string`

Comment: I think you need to re-read the documentation. What you have doesn't make any sense. You'll see why once you read the docs again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well in the documentation for getFirstRow() it states that you can use

```
$row = $query->getFirstRow() // which will give you an object
```

OR

```
$row = $query->getFirstRow(‘array’) // which will give you an Array
```

So your error message, which states...

```
Argument 1 passed to CodeIgniter\Database\BaseResult::getFirstRow()
must be  of the type string, object given
```

Would make you look and say to yourself, I had better go and read the documentation. So you can either pass in nothing, or a String 'array'.

So now can you see why

```
$query->getFirstRow($query))
```

does not make any sense! Why would you pass in the $query object as parameter.

You may have misread the documentation. I see you stated `getFirstRow([$type = 'object'])`

You might have got a little confused by that...

[$type = 'object'] means that the $type is defaulted to be the string 'object' so the returned type is an object by default with No Parameter being passed in.

If you want it to return an array, then you would specify the string 'array'. So then the $type parameter would be set to the string 'array' and return an array instead of an object.

Does that help!

Comment: Many thanks.  Sorry, I thought the getFirstRow([$type = 'object']) meant I have to supply an object.  Ok, makes sense and 'object' is the default type as set in getFirstRow().  Thank you VERY much for the detailed reply and learnt a lot.  Thanks.